# Is there an advantage to buying the locked weapons?

Tags: planetside-2

So I play as the NC Heavy Assualt unit most of the time, I have already put hundreds of certifications into the starting weapon, the Guass SAW I believe its called. I was planning on supporting the game and becoming a premium player for a bit, eventually. I'm not willing to give up what i've already put into the starter weapon by purchasing one or two of the locked weapons unless there is a noticable advantage to having some of the locked weapons. Obviously there are different types of weapons such as shotguns and rifles, but im specifically talking about each class of weapon in general, like all Light Machine Guns (LMG). **Are all weapon classes balanced, or is there a noticable advantage to aqcuiring locked weapons?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The weapons in PS2 are balanced and designed to be sideways upgrades;  some are more effective that others in particular situations.  The default guns are good all-rounders. LMG's have a large magazine and carbines are better at range. Each weapon will have it's own characteristics such as kick direction, full auto effectiveness and stopping power so you should always trial a weapon before deciding to purchase it.

For Heavy Assault there is one caveat; the rocket launchers. Personally I spent some station cash for the guided vehicle launcher and it has had a big impact on my play-style.

Comment: Yah i was definately going to buy the rocket launchers, is there a way to trial weapons?

Comment: @Paralytic - yes see [link](http://www.planetside2.com/news/planetside2-weapon-trials) for instructions.  You need enough SC or certs to make the purchase to be able to trial it.  You can only trial a weapon once every 8 hours and are available for load-out for 30 minutes.